# Why do I get 0.0 when I divide these two integers?

Tags: java

I am trying to show the percentage of day passed using a fixed time. However, when I divide the time passed already by the total amount of time (in seconds) of a day, I get 0.0. I put the current values into the console. Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Please show how they are computed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are performing integer division, and *then* casting it to a `double`. You should be doing:

```
int numOfSecondsSinceMidnight = 61960;
int totalDay = 86400;
double percentDayPassed = 0;
percentDayPassed = (((double)numOfSecondsSinceMidnight / totalDay)*100);
System.out.println(percentDayPassed);
```

Or better yet, changing `numOfSecondsSinceMidnight` and `totalDay` to `double`s:

```
double numOfSecondsSinceMidnight = 61960;
double totalDay = 86400;
double percentDayPassed = 0;
percentDayPassed = ((numOfSecondsSinceMidnight / totalDay)*100);
System.out.println(percentDayPassed);
```

Both of which print:

```
71.71296296296296
```